# Probability of a geometric distribution variable being greater than the other

Tags: probability-theory

Consider $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables with geometric distribution of parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively. Show that $P[X \ge Y] =\frac{p_2}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}$

Tip: for random variables with geometric distribution, $P[X=x] = p(1-p)^{x-1}$

Please, could anyone tell me why my solution is wrong and how would you explain to someone who is in his first probability course and with no use of calculus?

$Y$ and $X$ can be any number but:

if $Y = 1$ then $X=1 \cup X=2 \cup \dots $

if $Y = 2$ then $X=2 \cup X=3 \cup \dots $

$P[X \ge Y] = P[X=1 \cup X=2 \cup \dots /Y=1] + P[X=2 \cup X=3 \cup \dots / Y=2] + \dots$

Using the conditional probability formula:

$P[X \ge Y] = \frac{P[X=1 \cup X=2 \cup \dots \cap Y=1]}{P[Y=1]} + \frac{P[X=2 \cup X=3 \cup \dots \cap Y=2]}{P[Y=2]}+\dots$

The unions are disjoint events, so I can write as the sum of probabilities and the intersections are between independent events (X and Y):

$P[X \ge Y] = \frac{\{P[X=1] +P[X=2]+\dots\}P[Y=1]}{P[Y=1]} + \frac{\{P[X=2] +P[X=3]+\dots\}P[Y=2]}{P[Y=2]}+\dots$

Only here became evident to me that it's wrong, since $P[Y=y]$ will disapear and my solution will be in terms of $p_1$ only.

Comment: Just consider what happens on the first round. You either lose (because $X$ succeeds and $Y$ fails or you win (because $Y$ succeeds) or you restart the process.  Just write that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is wrong because you should write "and" in place of "given":
$$
\begin{align}
P(X\ge Y)&= P\left(\big[(X=1)\cup(X=2)\cup\cdots\big]\cap (Y=1)\right)\\
&+ P\left(\big[(X=2)\cup(X=3)\cup\cdots\big]\cap (Y=2)\right)\\
&+ P\left(\big[(X=3)\cup(X=4)\cup\cdots\big]\cap (Y=3)\right)\\
&+\cdots
\end{align}$$ Keep going, using independence:
$$
\begin{align}
P(X\ge Y)&= P\big((X=1)\cup(X=2)\cup\cdots\big)P(Y=1)\\
&+P\big((X=2)\cup(X=3)\cup\cdots\big)P(Y=2)\\
&+P\big((X=3)\cup(X=4)\cup\cdots\big)P(Y=3)\\
&+\cdots
\end{align}$$
and you'll get the desired result. Using summation notation, you would write
$$\begin{align}P(X\ge Y)=\sum_{y=1}^\infty P(Y=y,X\ge y)&=\sum_{y=1}^\infty P(Y=y)P(X\ge y)\\&=\sum_{y=1}^\infty P(Y=y)\sum_{x=y}^\infty P(X=x),\end{align}
$$ then use the Tip.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution! Could you help me understand just the first part, please? I understand what you mean by "and" and "given", but how did you know it's "and"? I used conditionals and you used just the intersections. I know X and Y are independent, but still I can't understand why we can't use conditionals. If we want X greater than Y, it makes sense to me to assume (given) every value of Y, we consider every value of X greater than a given value of Y. (sorry if it's too long or repetitive)

Comment: @Matheus You use "and" because the event $\{X\ge Y\}$ is decomposed as the union $$\{X\ge Y, Y=1\} \cup \{X\ge Y, Y=2\} \cup \{X\ge Y, Y=3\}\cup\cdots.$$ This is a disjoint union, so you apply $P$ to each event in the RHS. You can achieve this decomposition using "given": $$P(X\ge Y)=P(X\ge Y\mid Y=1)P(Y=1) + P(X\ge Y\mid Y=2)P(Y=2) + P(X\ge Y\mid Y=3)P(Y=3)+\cdots$$ but note the difference with your approach, which is missing the factors $P(Y=1)$, $P(Y=2)$, $P(Y=3)$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much!